# redirect to tab when the link is clicked

Tags: angularjs, redirect, ngroute, route-provider, angular-ui-tabset

```
<uib-tabset active="selectedTab"> 
<uib-tab index="0" id="termsAndCondiotionTab" heading="TnCs">
<div class="panel-body">        
<form name="TandC" ng-submit="saveTermsAndConditions()">
<input type="radio" type="radio">Yes
<input type="radio" type="radio">No
<button type="submit" id="conditionSubmit" class="bin btn-primary">NEXT</button>                            
</uib-tab>
<uib-tab index="1" id="infrastructureTab" heading="Infrastructure ">
<div class="panel-body">        
    <form name="Infrastructure" ng-submit="saveInfrastructure()">
    <label>Terms and Conditions </label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="object.infrastructure" type="radio">Yes
        <input type="radio" ng-model="object.infrastructure" type="radio">No
        <button type="submit" id="infraSubmit"  class="btn btn-primary">NEXT</button>
        </div>
</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Have created 5 tabs using tabset. 5th tab is the summary for the remaining 4 tabs. In the 5th tab there are links. Clicking on each link should open the respective tab. How to implement using angular js?

Comment: Why don't you explore route-provider or ui-router features ? What have you tried for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simply call a function from **ng-click** 
passing tab index which will change the
 **selectedTab**

Since you would already have written functions for each tab in case it get active. so no need to write code for routing again.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround method is to manipulate the active parameter in angularUI tabset. Everything you need is to pass an id of tab to activate  to tabset somehow.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs